# Is there any method to perform something parallel in postgresql extension?

Tags: postgresql, parallelism, multi-thread

According to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331421/is-it-ok-to-use-multi-thread-in-postgresql-extension) link, to perform something parallel in postgresql extension, multi-thread isn't an option.

So is there any other method? Such as some API and usage about multi-process? Maybe let me konw where can I find any example code?

Or the expection itself of performing something parallel in Postgresql extension does not reasonable at all? Would you provide some explanation?

Updated:
Regarding the things I want to parallelize, it generally has nothing with Postgresql, but caculate hash of a bunch of data

Comment: If your extension declares functions, then just declaring them to be parallel safe (assuming they are) would allow PostgreSQL to parallelize them automatically.  If it does something else, we would need to know what that something else is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to write a [custom background worker process](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bgworker.html) that starts additional helper processes.